# ASP.Net display a loading overlay on new page

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I currently have two pages in my ASP.net web forms site. On the first page the user can enter some details and then press a button. This will then response.redirect to the next page sending the user details with it.

This next page has a page load of

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {   
            GetInformation();        
        }
    }
```

GetInformation() does a long processing using those user details that takes about 15-20 seconds.

What happens is when the user presses the button on the first page, it stays on the first page until the GetInformation() has finished running, then it will load the new page.

What I want to do is, when the user presses the button, the new page appear and then have an overlay saying loading or something, and then have it start GetInformation(). Once GetInformation has finished the overlay will disappear.

I have done a search around on Google and seen some ideas but none of them seem to really fit to my problem.

What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page would be shown only after the `page_load` event has executed completely.So dont call ur function in the `page_load` event.Instead use a timer control to trigger ur function call.

Let say u add a timer control like

```
<asp:Timer ID="tmr" runat="server" Interval="3000" OnTick="tmr_Tick" Enabled="true">
</asp:Timer>
```

Now server side code would some what look like this

```
protected void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    tmr.Enabled = false;
    GetInformation();        
    loadingIndicator.Style.Add("display", "none");
}
```

Now in order to show loading indicator put a div like this on the page

```
<div id="loadingIndicator" runat="server" style="background-image:url(ajax-loader-small.gif);background-repeat: no-repeat; width: 100%; height: 104px; background-position: center;">
</div>
```

the loading indicator will be showing by default and when the `GetInformation()` has finished executing we can change display

Hope this helps....

Comment: how would that loading indicator be shown from the server code? your current code will not work

Comment: Seems to have worked so far, thanks. Still need to tweak my code a bit I think because the browser has shown all the details it retrieved but it still says connecting on the tab as if it's still trying to do something.

Comment: if u want me to look into the code den plz update ur code in ur question

Comment: Was my fault I didn't stop the timer. How would I turn your code into an overlay? At the moment it just appears at the top of the page then when the timer up disappers and all my data loads. I'd like it to cover the entire page.

Comment: there must be some jquery plugins to put an overlay.a simple google search would give u lots of options :)

Comment: In the code you put loadingIndicator.Style.Add("display", "none"); i tried to put loadingIndicator.Style.Add("display", "block"); when I click the button to show it again but it doesn't work?

Comment: Should point out for anyone who reads this, that loadingIndicator.Style.Add("display", "none"); doesn't work in internet explorer. I've not found a solution to make it work yet either.

Answer (score 1):

Very simple solution:

1. Create a new page `Loading.aspx`. Add appropriate styles and everything so that it looks like your expected loading page.
2. In this page add the following tag within the `<head>` tag: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL='LongLoadingPage.aspx'" />`

Now instead of redirecting to `LongLoadingPage.aspx` directly, redirect to the `Loading.aspx` page.

Of course, this is a quick-n-dirty solution, there might be a better one where you initialize the long running operation using AJAX requests (using `UpdatePanel` or vanilla `XMLHttpRequest`).

Comment: Thanks, this was my backup solution!